# Android app not working after export signed application from Eclipse

Tags: android, google-maps

I created an app that is using the Maps API. When I run the application from Eclipse using my Nexus 7 the app works fine and the maps load.

After exporting the application I install the .apk file but on start-up the map doesn't load.

Why would this be happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you followed all procedure for integrate google Map API??

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the Maps API key to production rather than debug. If you are using version 2, the key is in the Manifest file.